# $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2\exp\left(-x^{-2}\right)}{x^{3}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2\exp\left(-x^{-2}\right)}{x^{3}}$$

L'Hopital doesn't help much here because exponent will generate additional $2x^{-3}$ constantly.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Change variables $y={1\over x}$ this produces

$$\lim_{y\to\pm\infty} y^3e^{-y^2}=\lim_{y\to\pm\infty} {y^3\over e^{y^2}}$$

which you can evaluate using the rule.